# Android 4.4 (Kitkat) and volume problem on a Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, bugs

I've got a Nexus 7 tablet and it has just got updated to Android 4.4 - Kitkat automatically (I just approved the installation). Having done that, the sound volume of my tablet is acting weird. Once I push higher or lower volume buttons (on the case) it shows up the volume indicator and the volume handler moves one step in the requested direction (to this point it is normal).

From this point on the volume acts weird. If I keep pressing the volume buttons the volume indicator on the screen won't move anymore but the sound volume will be changed. And worse than that, the volume can not be adjusted using the on screen handler (you can not adjust volume with on screen touches).

Has anyone faced any similar problem? And more importantly is there any cure for it?

Comment: Which Nexus 7 do you have? The original one, or the newer one with two cameras?

Comment: The old one with just one front camera.

Comment: I have the same one and I don't see this behaviour after updating to KitKat.

Comment: Then it makes one of us. Do you have any suggestions what might have gone wrong? Or how can I resolve it?

Comment: If I did I'd already have answered your question! Just be patient and I'm sure someone who knows will answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the exact same issue on my Nexus 10 after upgrading to KitKat. Cycling power on the device after the update resolved the problem for me.

Comment: @Peanut Why not? To me, the second sentence seems to be a valid solution, if it works.

Comment: @Izzy I... I'm not sure. I don't even remember reviewing this an hour ago :/ Apologies to the answerer. Removed the comment.